# Simple encryption for ubuntu

Tags: encryption

How can I set an encrypted directory. Once accessed with a password, all files saved into it should be encrypted on the fly. It has to be possible to back-up as it were just a big file. And I don't have any interest into full-disk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ecryptfs-setup-private` from

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

More info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs and  https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html